# Merging two arrays with the same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I need a help with merging two arrays. Let's say I have following arrays:

```
Array
(
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Lorem
        [type] => pl
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Ipsum
        [type] => pl
    )

)
```

And the second one:

```
Array
(
    [6] => Sit dolor
    [4] => nostrud exercitation ullamco
    [3] => uuntur magni dolores
    [2] => corporis suscipit laboriosam
    [7] =>  quia non numquam eius modi tempora
 )
```

And desired output is:

```
Array
(
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Lorem
        [type] => pl
        [new_key] => uuntur magni dolores
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Ipsum
        [type] => pl
        [new_key] => corporis suscipit laboriosam
    )
)
```

I have been trying to compare arrays with `array_diff_key()` method and than merge arrays in some loop, but I could't get it working. Is there any built in PHP function, or should I write my own? If so, could you help me with getting desired result? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you try `array_merge_recursive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate over first array:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key=> $item) {
    $arr1[$key]['new_key'] = isset($arr2[$item['id']]) ? $arr2[$item['id']] : '';
}
```

Or

```
foreach ($arr1 as &$item) { //just for fun
    $item['new_key'] = isset($arr2[$item['id']]) ? $arr2[$item['id']] : '';
}
```

But it seems that your data comes from database. If I am right, you'd better use sql [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Answer (score 5):

All you need is

```
$data = array_map(function ($v) use($new) {
    isset($new[$v['id']]) and $v['new_key'] = $new[$v['id']] ;
    return $v;
}, $data);

var_dump($data);
```

Output ( [DEMO](http://eval.in/9745) )

```
array (size=2)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 3
      'name' => string 'Lorem' (length=5)
      'type' => string 'pl' (length=2)
      'new_key' => string 'uuntur magni dolores' (length=20)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'Ipsum' (length=5)
      'type' => string 'pl' (length=2)
      'new_key' => string 'corporis suscipit laboriosam' (length=28)
```

Comment: +1 since it's right answer but I am against this approach. First of all, it's less readable than _traditional one_. Secondly, if another developer with lacking experience working with php had to analyze this, (s)he'd spend valuable time. ;) Anyway, this is what OP wanted.

Comment: Yes, that's interesting solution, but I am begginer developer and it did took me some time to understand it. I have never used anonymous functions in PHP before.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do like this also

```
foreach($arr1 as $key => $arr) {

        $arr1[$key]['new_key'] = isset($arr2[$key])?$arr2[$key]:'';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$first_array  = Array("3" => Array("id" => 3,"name" => "Lorem","type" => "pl"),
                      "2" => Array("id" => 2,"name" => "Ipsum","type" => "pl")
                     );

$sec_array   = Array("6" => "Sit dolor",
                    "4" => "nostrud exercitation ullamco",
                    "3" => "uuntur magni dolores",
                    "2" => "corporis suscipit laboriosam",
                    "7" =>  "quia non numquam eius modi tempora",
                 );

$res_array   = array();
foreach($first_array as $key=>$val){
     if(array_key_exists($key,$sec_array)){
        $val["new_key"] = $sec_array[$key];
     }
     $res_array[$key]   = $val;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res_array);
?>
```