# Merge Two Array Element with Same element

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array via api calling.

```
    $array1 = array(
    0 => array(
        'rest_id' => 8,
        'price_rates' => Array(
                       'menu' => Array(
                                        0 => Array(
                                            'menu_id' => 'm11',
                                            'price' => 100
                                        )                
                                ),
                        'comparision' => 'superior'
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'rest_id' => 9,
        'price_rates' => Array(
                                'menu' => Array(
                                                0 => Array(
                                                    'menu_id' => 'm22',
                                                    'price' => 80
                                                )              
                                ),
            'comparision' => 'medium'
        )
    ),
    2 => array(
        'rest_id' => 400,
        'price_rates' => Array(
                                'menu' => Array(
                                                0 => Array(
                                                    'menu_id' => 'm401',
                                                    'price' => 33
                                                )                
                                ),
            'comparision' => 'low'
        )
    )
);

    $array2 = array(
    0 => array(
        'address' => 'No.12,XXX country',   
        'rest_id' => 400    
    ),
    1 => array(
        'address' => 'No.18,XYZ country',   
        'rest_id' => 8    
    )
);
```

I want to merge these two array with 'rest_id' that only include in 2nd array. And the desired output is

```
$result_array = array(
0 => array(
    'rest_id' => 8,
    'price_rates' => Array(
                   'menu' => Array(
                                    0 => Array(
                                        'menu_id' => 'm11',
                                        'price' => 100
                                    )                
                            ),
                    'comparision' => 'superior'
    ),
    'address' => 'No.18,XYZ country'
),
1 => array(
    'rest_id' => 400,
    'price_rates' => Array(
                            'menu' => Array(
                                            0 => Array(
                                                'menu_id' => 'm401',
                                                'price' => 33
                                            )                
                            ),
        'comparision' => 'low'
    ),
    'address' => 'No.12,XXX country'
)

);
```

Is it possible? I have searched similar questions.But can't find answers. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Yes this is possible.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633918/combining-two-arrays-by-id-in-php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853261/merging-two-arrays-with-the-same-keys

Comment: You will need to write custom loops for achieving this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633918/combining-two-arrays-by-id-in-php  That one merging both arrays. My result array should be included values that are in both arrays.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with custom loop as comment suggestion.

```
$result = array();

foreach($array1 as $values)
{
foreach($array2 as $values2)
{
    if($values['rest_id'] == $values2['rest_id'])
    {
        $result[] = array_merge_recursive($values, $values2);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Although 'rest_id' element changed string to array at result array coz of array_merge_recursive() function, I can now easily manage it.

```
[rest_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 400
                [1] => 400
            )
```

Thank you for all suggestions and answer :)

Answer (score -1):

This code should do the trick:

```
foreach($array2 as $key=>$val) {
    $array1[$key]['address'] = $val;
}
```

(This will result in `$array1` including all values)

Comment: This is not what is asked. The OP wants only values that are in both arrays (rest_id=9 should not be in the output from the exemple).